# Itertools.combinations() raising Time Limit Exceeded

Tags: python, python-3.x, performance

I am trying to solve this Python coding problem:

> Description: Teacher Ambrosio is teaching binary numbers to his
>   daughter Ambrosinita, so he decided to create a game.
>
> Ambrosio will give N numbers to Ambrosinita, who can choose K numbers
>   among the initial N. For each number chosen, she earns a score
>   equivalent to the number of 1's using the binary representation of the
>   number.
>
> Help Ambrosinita to find how many points she can earn.
>
> Entry:
>
> The first input line contains an integer T, which indicates the number
>   of test cases.
>
> Each test case starts with a line containing integers N(total numbers)
>   and K(numbers that can be chosen).
>
> The last input line of each case contains N integers, representing the
>   numbers that Ambrosinita can choose.
>
> Output:
>
> For each test case print a line containing how many points Ambrosinita
>   can earn.

1 ≤ T ≤ 10

1 ≤ N ≤ 10^3

0 ≤ K ≤ N

0 ≤ Numbers ≤10^5

There's an execution time limit of 2 seconds. I am getting a TLE Error, but the output is the same as expected. Thus, inputs must have a certain length.

Here's my code:

```
import itertools

test_cases = int(input())

def binary(num):
    return format(num,'b')

def filter_string_1s(string):
    aux = ''
    for i in string:
        if i == '1':
            aux += i
    return aux

for i in range(test_cases):
    k = input().split()
    k = int(k[1])
    values = input().split()
    values = [int(i) for i in values]
    values = [filter_string_1s(str(binary(i))) for i in values]
    bin_values = []
    for combination in itertools.combinations(values,k):
        aux = 0
        for bin_number in combination:
            for i in bin_number:
                if i == '1':
                    aux += 1
        bin_values.append(aux)
    print(max(bin_values))
```

Question: What steps should I take to optimize it in order to solve the problem within the execution time limit?

TLE = Time Limit Exceeded

Comment: Please edit the problem into your question. I can't view it by following the link.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! Please provide a brief description of the problem you're trying to solve rather than a link to an external site

Comment: Do you know why it is taking over 2 seconds?  How many iterations do you think the loop `itertools.combinations(values,k)` will do?

Comment: @KevinWang I tried removing repeated elements from the list before using itertools.combinations() but it didn't work (I still got TLE).

Comment: @flsantos0101 how many iterations will there be, though?  How big can the size of `values` be?

Comment: @KevinWang Updated the problem info. 1 ≤ N ≤ 10^3

Comment: Start by getting rid of obvious time wasters like `binary`, and inline the call to `format(i, 'b')`.

Comment: @flsantos0101 So N can go up to 1000, and K can be anywhere from 1 to N.  What if N is 1000 and K is 10?  How many combinations will there be?

Comment: And just `''.join` rather than repeated string concatenation. `filter_string_1s` as written is O(n^2); `''.join([i for i in string if i == '1'])` is O(n).

Comment: And finally, `aux = sum(big_number.count('1') for big_number in combination)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a "top-k" problem, not a problem requiring "k" combinations.  For sake of reading, let's pick N = 990, K = 7.  You need to choose the top 7 scores in a list of 990.

You did this by generating C(990, 7) = 912,459,983,564,271,542,400 combinations, and *then* determining how many `1` bits are in each of the 7 numbers in each combination.  This is why you're running out of time: you have 990 numbers to consider, but you're repeating the bit count gazillions of times for each number in the input.

Knock it off.  All you need is to go through that list *once* and keep the top 7 bit counts.  There are no interactions between the 7 numbers in the list.  In fact you don't even have to report the numbers, merely the total score.

Start with a list of seven zeros.  Now iterate through all 990 numbers.  Any time you find a bit-count larger than the smallest element of the list (keep it sorted for ease of reference), then replace it with the new score (and re-sort).  At the end of all 990 numbers, `sum` the list.

Also counting bits is much easier than you're doing.  Convert the `int` to a binary string and use `str.count(1)` to see how many `1` bits are in it.

Comment: Note: The algorithm described in paragraph 4 is essentially what `heapq.nlargest` would do for you (it doesn't keep it sorted, it just keeps it a heap, sorting as the last step; maintaining a heap invariant being slightly cheaper than maintaining a fully sorted state).

Answer (score 0):

The maximum points she can make will be by selecting the K numbers that have the most 1 bits.  So you simply need to compute the points for each number and take the top K.

for example:

```
import random

def maxPoints(K,N=None,numbers=None):
    numbers = numbers or [random.randrange(0,100001) for _ in range(N)]
    points  = sorted(bin(n).count("1") for n in numbers)
    return sum(points[-K:])

mp = maxPoints(3,numbers=[1,2,3,4,5])
print(mp) # 5

mp = maxPoints(1000,1000) 
print(mp) # will return instantly
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved! Thanks everyone.

Code:

```
test_cases = int(input())

for i in range(test_cases):
    k = input().split()
    k = int(k[1])
    nums = input().split()
    nums = [format(int(i),'b').count('1') for i in nums]
    nums.sort()
    sum = 0
    for i in range(k):
        sum += nums[-1]
        del nums[-1]
    print(sum)
```

Comment: First off, `sum = 0` `for i in range(k):`, `sum += nums[-1]`, `del nums[-1]` is a slow way to spell `mysum = sum(nums[-k:])` (note, variable name change; `sum` is a built-in, so you can't use it if you name a local variable `sum`). Two, if imports are allowed, and the total size of `nums` is large enough, you might benefit a little from replacing your use of `sort` and slicing with `import`ing `heapq` and using `heapq.nlargest` (which returns a `list` of only the `k` largest elements, with `O(n log k)` instead of sortings `O(n log n)` work).

Comment: Insightful comment! The above code has an execution time of 0.0448s. After editing as suggested, it slightly decreased to 0.0479s. Thanks!